# How to test Shopware 6 APIs manually using PhpStorm REST API client

Tags: rest, phpstorm, shopware6, shopware6-api

Shopware 6 provides a REST API, which uses a token that expires every 10 minutes.

When running manual API tests using PhpStorm this is annoying. How can this be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm can run multiple requests. We first define the client id and client secret in the Shopware 6 admin panel. Next we use this to obtain the short live token and then execute our request.

1. Create a new `test.http` file in PhpStorm
2. Insert the following:

   ```
   POST {{baseurl}}/api/oauth/token
   Content-Type: application/json

   {
       "grant_type": "client_credentials",
       "client_id": "{{client_id}}",
       "client_secret": "{{client_secret}}"
   }

   > {%
       client.global.set("token", response.body.access_token);
   %}

   ###
   POST {{baseurl}}/api/the-api-you-want-to-check
   Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Type: application/json
   ```
3. Under the menu "run with" define a new environment
4. Add you integration under System -> Integration in the Shopware Admin panel

   [image: Adding secret]
5. Add the `baseurl`, the `client_id` and the `client_secret` to the environment:

   ```json
   {
     "dev": {
       "baseurl": "https://example.com.local/",
       "client_id": "SWIADNHZQMVJMKFTRDLUCEOXTA",
       "client_secret": "MXRFbUxlMlcxRExvQmFFWXZnZjRXU1JqVVFRUWlES29yTldaQ1k",
     }
   }
   ```
6. Execute the request

By adding the variables to the environment, you can also commit your `test.http` file to a `dev` folder or similar in your version control system to share it with other developers.